# Symfony advanced search with Ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, search, ajaxform

I want to implement a search using ajax however, I keep facing this error:

> Entity 'App\Entity\Repas' has no field 'string'. You can therefore not
> call 'findBystring' on the entities' repository.

I tried changing the name of the Function but it says that it should start by `findBy`, I don't know where else to look honestly.
Controller code:

```
use App\Entity\Repas;
use App\Form\RepasType;
use App\Repository\RepasRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

public function searchAction(Request $request)
  {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(repas::class);
    $requestString= $request->get('searchValue');
    $repas = $repository->findBystring($requestString);
    $jsonContent = $Normalizer->normalize($repas, 'json',['groups'=>'repas']);
    $retour=json_encode($jsonContent);
    return new Response($retour);

  }
```

Doctrine Repository function:

```
public function findByString($nom){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('repas')
            ->where('repas.nom like :nom')
            ->setParameter('nom', '%'.$nom.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Twig code :

```
<h1 id="dd1"> List</h1>
</br>
<div style="margin-right:50px;" class="btn btn-primary">
    <a href="#"> Add</a>
</div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<div>
    <table border="1" id="t" class="table table-hover table-dark">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Nom</td>
                <td>desc</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="all">
            {% for repa in repas %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ repa.id }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ repa.nom }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ repa.desc }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="search"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").keyup(function(e) {

            var value = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('list') }}",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    'searchValue': value
                },
                success: function(retour) {
                    if (retour) {
                        $('#t tbody#search').empty();
                        $.each(JSON.parse(retour), function(i, obj) {
                            $('#t tbody#all').hide();
                            $('#t tbody#search').append('<tr><td> ' + obj.id + '  </td><td>    ' + obj.nom '  </td><td>' + obj.desc + ' </td><td><a href="#/' + obj.id + '">update</a> </br><a href="#/' + obj.id + '">Delete</a></td></tr>');
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#t tbody#all').show();
                        $('#t tbody#search').empty();
                        $('#t tbody#search').fadeIn('fast');
                    }
                },
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo/Caps error!

You defined a function inside your repository called `findByString()` , and inside your controller, you are calling it `findBystring()`

Inside your controller Change:

```
$repas = $repository->findBystring($requestString);
```

To:

```
$repas = $repository->findByString($requestString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You repository RepasRepository is not called, so you function is not recognized. This is the correction of your action body:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(RepasRepository::class); // repa => RepasRepository
$requestString= $request->get('searchValue');
$repas = $repository->findByString($requestString);  // findBystring => findByString
$jsonContent = $Normalizer->normalize($repas, 'json',['groups'=>'repas']);
$retour=json_encode($jsonContent);
return new Response($retour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `findBy` with such syntax:

```
$repository->findBy(['nom'=> $requestString]);
```

That hovewer will return only entities matching the string exactly.

Have you tried just renaming the repository method?

Comment: NO actually i am still new to symfony  and I am having some issues understanding everything

Comment: Ok what I meant is to rename the `findByString` method you are using here to something else like `findRepasByNameLike` (just an example), but I think the answer below would be correct, you have a typo in your controller code.